# How to deploy the android application to emulator like Application Deployment of WP7

Tags: android-emulator

I have developed the Hello World Android application using Eclipse. I can run the application in the android emulator through this eclipse. But i want to run the apk files using Android emulator without opening the Eclipse(like WP7 xap files are running through Application Deployment Software without opening the VisualStudio). How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the following procedure.

**Procedure to run the apk files in Android Emulator without opening the Eclipse:**

1. Check your installed directory(ex: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools), whether it has the adb.exe or not). 
   If not present in this folder, then download the attachment [here](http://www.botskool.com/downloads/geeks/android/adb.zip), extract the zip files. You will get adb files, copy and paste those three files inside tools folder
2. **Run AVD manager** from C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk and start the Android Emulator.
3. **Copy and paste the apk file** inside the C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools
4. Go to **Start -> Run -> cmd**
5. Type cd “C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools”
6. Type adb **install example.apk**
7. After getting **success** command
8. Go to Application icon in Android emulator, we can see the your application

Thank you.